# What is the difference between viscosity and shear viscosity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, definition, viscosity

Are the terms [shear viscosity](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=shear+viscosity) and [viscosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity) for fluids interchangeable, or do they mean different things?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are the same.

One reason why you might encounter the term *shear viscosity* is to distinguish it from [bulk viscosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_viscosity) for example.